# Почему не выводится результат арифметических вычислений при if?

Tags: python, if

Как вывести конечный результат вычислений при условии "if"?

```
a = 1
if a == 1:
    a+1
else:
    a-1
print(a)
```

выводит все-равно 1

Comment: Потому что `a + 1` это выражение, возвращающее результат. Его нужно куда то сохранить. Например, `a = a + 1` или короче: `a += 1`

Answer (score 2):

потому что

```
a = a + 1
a = a - 1
```

или

```
a += 1
a -= 1
```

все таки лучше почитать начало учебника по питону и работе с переменными

P.S.

так же вашу конструкцию можно записать так:

```
a = (a + 1) if a == 1 else (a - 1)
```

или

```
a = a + 1 if a == 1 else -1
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, просто я слегка затупок и только начинаю знакомиться с ЯП :)